Why aren't there any salary-related questions in this year's developer survey?
I rely on the Stack Overflow developer survey for salary data instead of LinkedIn/whatever because of the extremely high signal-to-noise ratio.
You have a detailed breakdown on years of experience, geography, and profession types. Also, people who are active on Stack Overflow enough to fill the survey tend to be better programmers, so the numbers cited on Stack Overflow developer survey is typically much higher than LinkedIn. It is a more accurate representation of my demographic.
There is also job satisfaction data by developer type, which, to my knowledge, nobody does.
Being able to download the data and run my own analysis is something I do every year. You can't export raw data from LinkedIn.
Apparently, other people got the question, but I didn't for whatever reason.

From The 2024 Developer Survey Launches Today: "Note that, as with last year's survey, we will be asking a smaller quantity of personal demographic questions" I assume that is one of the questions that was removed as one those questions.

There was one, just a flat text input question for how much you roughly make annually. And IMO, that's enough.

I didn't get it? Was it a bug or A/B testing?

There is no way for anyone to answer that. Maybe you just blinked and missed it because it really was that type of undercooked question, somewhere in the early stages of the survey.

I was looking forward to it, I do every year. No way I missed it.

I admit, I don't recall seeing that question either, @Gimby , hence my assumption on the reason for its removal.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430319/6296561 indicates the question does exist

It's 72% into the survey (skipping the ai section, not sure if that changes %)

When I got to that page, it only asked me where I live, and then skipped on to the next page.

I also didn't see a salary question, only the "Where do you live" section of the page. Could it be based on location?

Looking at the request for the question (QID51) it looks like it has some logic for displaying. No idea what framework it uses though: https://pastebin.com/u7m0duAn

There was a text field for salary, at least in my case. I believe it was below the dropdown for years of experience.

"Also, people who are active on Stack Overflow enough to fill the survey tend to be better programmers" [citation needed]. Bold assumption to correlate activity in Stack Overflow and/or willingness to fill the survey with programming skills. Even bolder to assume better programmers (by which metric?) get payed higher salaries.

Your skill is more influential on if you manage to hold a job or not, not necessarily your salary - also not an unimportant factor in this day and age by the way. You might argue that skill will land you a job with big tech more easily, but... I would think that this is less programming skill and more networking skill.

Looking at the request in the network inspector when you get to the page (partial pastebin of response), the question (id QID51 in my case) has some conditional logic:

if ProfessionalDev equals True
and if employment status (QID296) is Employed, full-time, Employed, part-time, or Independent contractor, freelancer, or self-employed

I don't know what this is using to parse the logic so I might be a little off, but I opened the survey in incognito and confirmed that the page only asks where you live if you don't pick the right employment status.


I chose coding professionally and employed full-time, but did not get the salary question. I only got the "Where do you live?" question one.

I also choose coding professional and employed full-time. Only the "Where do you live" part was shown.

I confirm that picking Professionally & Full-Time I got this page, with both location & salary.

I got this question as a part-time worker in Switzerland. This year I had no idea whether they wanted to know the full-time interpolation or the actual (80%) salary. I suspect that data will not be very reliable this year

Yeah, what does "estimate an equivalent yearly salary" actually mean? If you earn $100 an hour and work 10 hours a week, 48 weeks a year, do you put in $48,000 or $192,000?

@MatthieuM. Thanks for testing, updated the answer! Maybe there are other checks for the first two comments?

I chose coding professionally and employed full-time as well and didn't get the salary question, only the location one.

@IslamHassan Maybe there's some other checks I couldn't find, until someone more knowledgeable comes along this is my best guess

Nice bit of detective work. So maybe a bug then, I got the question based on part-time and being a professional bodge artist.
